# SQL Get TRUE if two strings share any character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, contains, string-comparison

I wonder, if there is a trick for getting a boolean/bit result of comparison of two strings, where **TRUE** value would be returned if a **common character** between the two strings exist.

One string is a list of users granted access (i.e. "OTV", stored in user profile) and the other is a list of groups which have access to the object (i.e. "MDSKTUQ", stored in DB within the records). Each character is a name of a user group.

In real SQL query, I want to return rows, which contain any group granted to a user. Something like:

```
-- Following should display all files attached to record 145
-- to which has the user granted access:
SELECT FileCaption, FileName, FileType, Category FROM DocFiles 
WHERE RecordID = 145 AND CONTAINS(GroupsRead, <<list_of_groups_string>>)
```

I have a client-side solution, but feasible SQL-side solution would be more tidy and safer. 
Comments and discussion are appreciated.

Regards,

Oak

Comment: Can you add some sample table data, and the expected result. And tag the dbms used.

Comment: SQL is not a dbms. Tag the DBMS which you are using?\

Comment: There is a reason why multivalued fields are usually frowned upon when designing a database and that is precisely because queries against these fields become cumbersome or in some cases outright impossible to do. If you can, you should consider extracting that field out into a separate table with one row per group or user.

Comment: Sorry for the tag, I hope I did it correctly now (sql-server-2012)

Comment: Definitely doable but difficulty depends on RDBMS. [This reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm) might help. I would personally look at the `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE` functions to perform this action.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, I (hopefuly) understand the issue. There's a separate list of users (table) in final design. However, for the time-being, there's a simplified access rights design and I'd keep it client-side, if there's no feasible SQL solution (as I kind-of expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are - pressie!

```
ALTER FUNCTION StringContainsCharactersFrom 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @source varchar(100),
    @candidate varchar(100)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

    declare @candidatePos int = 1;
    while (@candidatePos <= len(@candidate))
    BEGIN

        declare @candidateLetter varchar = substring(@candidate, @candidatePos, 1);
        if (CHARINDEX(@candidateLetter,@source, 1) > 0)
            return 1;
        set @candidatePos = @candidatePos + 1;
    END
    return 0;

END
GO
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I.e.: WHERE ...... AND dbo.stringContainsCharactersFrom('OMT',DL.GroupsRead) = 1